# com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: androidx, bottomnavigationview

I am developing android news app using bottomnavigation view but when I run the app I am getting following exception

```
Process: yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari, PID: 19590
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari/yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference`
```

below MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

   val  bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom)



    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        var selectedFragment = Fragment()
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.top_headline -> selectedFragment = TopHeadlinesFragment()
            R.id.espn_news -> selectedFragment = ESPNFragment()
            R.id.bbc_sport -> selectedFragment = BBCSportFragment()
            R.id.football_italia -> selectedFragment = FootballItaliaFragment()
        }
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment)
        transaction.commit()
        return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

    }
}
```

}

below activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnews_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: findViewById(R.id.bottom). There isn't in your layout

Answer (score 0):

In your layout there is no id for the bottomNavigationView nor the framelayout.Add id's for both of them